# Fortran passing array element to array

Tags: fortran

I am not well versed in Fortran, but am trying to understand a Fortran function and how it is passing a parameter to a subroutine (so that I can code similar functionality, in C#). It happens to be SMOOTH from Carl de Boor's "A Practical Guide to Splines," but I'm simplifying for the sake of my question.

The function `SMOOTH` begins with something like this:

```
real function SMOOTH (x, y, dy, n, s, V, A) 
integer n, i, m
real A(n, 4), dy(n), s, V(n, 7), x(n), y(n)
call SETUPQ(x, dy, y, n, V, A(1, 4))
    ...
```

My understanding is that `A` and `V` are multi-dimensional arrays, with n rows each, and 4 and 7 columns, respectively. It appears that row 1, column 4 of `A` is being passed as the last parameter (`A(1, 4)`) in the `call SETUPQ` line.

The subroutine `SETUPQ` starts like this:

```
subroutine SETUPQ (x, dy, y, n, V, QTY)
integer n, i, m
real dy(n), QTY(n), V(n, 7), x(n), y(n)
    ...
```

Within `SETUPQ`, assignment is later made to the n elements of the `QTY` array.

My question is, why is `A(1, 4)` from `SMOOTH` being passed into `QTY` of `SETUPQ`? Isn't `A(1, 4)` simply a single value from `A`? Is `QTY` going to be assigned to `A(1, 4)`?

I'd appreciate any help toward understanding what is happening with that `call SETUPQ...` line.

Comment: The crucial expression is "sequence association", using which you can find any number of other examples and details.

Comment: @francescalus, thank you for the comment; I'll give that phrase a try in my search.